# Correct way to use register_activation_hook

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, activation

Hi I am developing a plugin and got stuck at one point. I have tried exploring different forums as well as WordPress codex but its not 100% clear. Can anyone help me understand how `register_activation_hook` actually works.

I have the following code that does not work:

```
register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'plugin_activation_fn'  );
      function plugin_activation_fn(){
      define('PLUGIN_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ));
      require_once PLUGIN_DIR . 'includes/contact.php';
}
```

But if I move that code outside of `register_activation_hook` function then it works fine

```
define('PLUGIN_DIR', plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ));
require_once PLUGIN_DIR . 'options.php';
require_once PLUGIN_DIR . 'includes/contactone.php';
```

`contact.php` contains the following code:

```
if (!empty($_GET['email']) && !empty($_GET['token'])) {
    add_action('init', 'my_test_fn', 0);
}
function my_test_fn(){
    echo'test';
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Please help.  thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This quotation from [The Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_activation_hook) clearly states what does this function do:

> The `register_activation_hook` function registers a plugin function to
>   be run when the plugin is activated.

This means, this function works similar as a class's `__construct()` method. You can use it to set initial options, update database, and more. It doesn't run every time the core is loaded, it only runs when you click the `Activate` button of a plugin in the plugins list.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. That makes sense. So If I am understanding it correctly, I should not include files in that hook and only use that for setting defaults, saving values to database etc. correct? What if I have to use `register_nav_menus`?

Comment: You are correct. This will only run once, so it's good for setting options and so, the same way `register_uninstall_hook` is good for clearing options. You should not include `register_nav_menus` in this hook, since the nav menus should be registered each time the core is initiated. The name `register` is a bit misleading here.

Comment: Perfect! makes sense now.  Thanks for all your help.